# How can add items to spinner with ArrayAdapter in Navigation drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I use strings.xml for my Items when I use it in simple Activity its works correctly but when i want to use it in Navigation drawer Activity it dosent work. the error is

> Error:(98, 51) error: incompatible types: ContactUsFragment cannot be
>   converted to Context
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

This is my Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="country_names">
        <item> select </item>
        <item>germany</item>
        <item>italy</item>
        <item>metro</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

i have problem in this line:

> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_names,
>   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

```
public class ContactUsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {
    GoogleMap map;
    public ContactUsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate( fragment_contact_us, container, false);
        return v;

    } //end of onCreateView

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated( view, savedInstanceState );


        spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById( R.id.spinner );
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById( R.id.map1 );
        mapFragment.getMapAsync( this );

    } // end of onViewCreated

    @Override
    public  void    onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
        map=googleMap;
        LatLng pp=new LatLng(12,25);
        MarkerOptions option=new MarkerOptions();
        option.position(pp).title("hi ");
        map.addMarker(option);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pp));

    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `context` is needed then you will have to pass the `activity` or `application`. In this context I think the `activity` will be enough

Change this line:

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

for this

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.country_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Note the `getActivity()` call